# Ubuntu Xenial: perf doesn't demangle C++ symbols

Tags: application-development, compiling, c++

Linux perf-tools don't seem to work as expected on Ubuntu (16.04). C++ symbols don't get unmangled, I only see garbled stuff like "_afki34334ldfjkdasf_dfkj".

Note that I have compiled the program and libraries with '-g' (although I saw that the library was compiled with -fomit-frame-pointer but I'm not sure if it matters).

Is this a bug, or is there a way to enable name demangling?

```
uname -r
4.4.0-21-generic

perf --version
perf version 4.4.6

aptitude search "~ilinux-tools"
i A linux-tools-4.4.0-21                           - Linux kernel version specific tools for version 4.4.0-21 
i A linux-tools-4.4.0-21-generic
```